Streamlit and Aggrid: if I dynamically add rows, how can automatically resize the grid when key-fixed?
I have a grid that has an "Add row" button. If I don't add a fixed key, the grid sometimes disappear or doesn't update correctly. If I add a fixed key, I can't find a way to resize the grid (or the inner container to be able to do vertical scroll). In this example, you can't scroll to see the new rows, and I don't find a way to change the height of the grid dynamically. This is a simple version of my problem:
from st_aggrid import GridOptionsBuilder, AgGrid
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

data = {
    'Name': ['John Doe', 'Jane Smith', 'Emily Jones', 'Chris Brown', 'Elijah Wood'],
    'Age': [28, 34, 22, 45, 40],
    'City': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'SFo']
}

gb = GridOptionsBuilder()
gb.configure_column("Name")
gb.configure_column("Age")
gb.configure_column("City")
go = gb.build()

if "slides_df" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.slides_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

grid_response = AgGrid(
    st.session_state.slides_df,
    fit_columns_on_grid_load=True,
    gridOptions=go,
    key="fixed",
)

if st.button("Add row"):
    new_slide = {'Name': 'XXX', 'Age': 50}
    st.session_state.slides_df = pd.concat([st.session_state.slides_df, pd.DataFrame([new_slide])], ignore_index=True)
    st.rerun()

Any ideas? Thanks!
